# Apache Flink - Unable to use local Kinesis for FlinkKinesisConsumer

Tags: java, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

So far I have followed the instructions documented for Flink's kinesis connector to use a local Kinesis.

### [Using Non-AWS Kinesis Endpoints for Testing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kinesis.html#using-non-aws-kinesis-endpoints-for-testing)

```
Properties producerConfig = new Properties();
producerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, "us-east-1");
producerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, "aws_access_key_id");
producerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, "aws_secret_access_key");
producerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ENDPOINT, "http://localhost:4567");
```

With a Flink producer, these instructions work with a local kinesis (I use Kinesalite).

However, with a Flink consumer, I get an exception that `aws.region` and `aws.endpoint` are not *both* allowed. But region is required, which means its not possible to override the endpoint.

> org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: For FlinkKinesisConsumer either AWS region ('aws.region') or AWS endpoint ('aws.endpoint') must be set in the config.

Is this a bug in the connector? I see a related PR: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/6045 .

I found a [workaround on Flink's mailing list](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Can-t-get-the-FlinkKinesisProducer-to-work-against-Kinesalite-for-tests-td23438.html), but they describe this as an issue for the producer and not the consumer, whereas i see the opposite (i think), so not sure about this. It's really confusing.

Comment: I flagged it up on Flink's jira too https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-13111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been some progress made since this question was asked.

The asker pushed the issue in [this jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-13111) which was marked as a duplicate of [this second jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-10190) .

The issue should now be resolved, and the fix available for version 1.10 and above.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is related to the `XOR` condition in the validation check.
As you can see, the `validateConsumerConfiguration` method perform an XOR validation in the if statement. So, you can only specify one of the two parameters checked.
[image]

For set a custom URL, you need to remove the `AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION` properties and use only the link.

```java
// Set the given URL
consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ENDPOINT, URL);
// Remove the region
consumerConfig.remove(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION);
```

This solution, fix the error related to the following StackTrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For FlinkKinesisConsumer either AWS region ('aws.region') or AWS endpoint ('aws.endpoint') must be set in the config.

at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.util.KinesisConfigUtil.validateConsumerConfiguration(KinesisConfigUtil.java:92)
```